# Shared UIImageView for background image throughout app - Singleton Property

Tags: iphone, uitableview, singleton

I have a UIImage that I use throughout my app as a background image for grouped UITableViews.

I thought that for efficiency I would alloc and init the UIView with my UIImage in my appDelegate and then access throughout my app. That way I would only allocate that imageView once and if I was drilling into a nav stack with multiple tableviews with this image I wouldn't need to worry about releasing and restoring the image as I descend and ascend or incur overhead at each step.

As soon as I tried this I noticed that it seems that the UITableView class is releasing the my shared image down to 0 and it therefore is going away. Makes perfect sense but I would need to prevent the image from ever hitting a 0 retain count for this to work.

Is this a totally goofy approach?

If it is not what's the best way to retain my shared ImageView? I know I could call retain when I setup each tableview's backgroundimage but I was wondering if there is a way to set the retain count of the shared UIImageView to NSUIntegerMax in my appDelegate. I've setup singleton classes before but in this case I'm trying to have a single property that is never released rather than creating a UIImageView singleton subclass.

Sorry if that's a little muddled and thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not worry so much as `+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name` are cached. 
From the spec:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.

Comment: Thank you. As always, premature optimization based on instinct rather than in response to a problems proves perilous.